# D3 animated scatter plot not displaying

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scatter

I am working on a d3.js Dashboard (so only one dashboard and many layouts). I wanted to display a scatterplot animated, with the dots moving regarding some filter I am applying.
But in order, I have to display something first which is not happening.
Here are my program, which is a `scatterplot.js` file in an MVC format.

```
function scatterplot(DOMElement){

    var scatObj = {}; // main object

    scatObj.setTooltipText = function(f){
        tooltipText = f;
        //updateInteractions();
        return scatObj;
    }
    scatObj.setMouseclickCallback = function(f){
        mouseclickCallback = f;
        //updateInteractions();
        return scatObj;
    }


    // function loading data and rendering it in scatter chart
    // parameters:
    //      - dataset in following format:
    //          [{"key": year, "value": money}, {...}, ...]
    // returns:
    //      - scatObj for chaining
    scatObj.loadAndRender = function(data){
        dataset = data;
        render();
        return scatObj;
    }

    // ---- PRIVATE VARIABLES

    // sizing vars
    var dataset = [];  // Initialize empty array
            var numDataPoints = dataset.length;
            for(var i=0; i<numDataPoints; i++) {
                var newNumber1 = d.value.x;  // New random integer
                var newNumber2 =  d.value.y;  // New random integer
                dataset.push([newNumber1, newNumber2]);  // Add new number to array
            }

    // Setup settings for graphic
    var canvas_width = 500;
    var canvas_height = 300;
    var padding = 30;  // for chart edges

    // Create scale functions
    var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()  // xScale is width of graphic
                                    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
                                            return d[0];  // input domain
                                    })])
                                    .range([padding, canvas_width - padding * 2]); // output range

    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()  // yScale is height of graphic
                                    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
                                            return d[1];  // input domain
                                    })])
                                    .range([canvas_height - padding, padding]);  // remember y starts on top going down so we flip

    // scales
    // Define X axis
    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
                                .scale(xScale)

    // Define Y axis
    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
                            .scale(yScale)


    var svg = d3.select("DOMElement")  // This is where we put our vis
                            .append("svg")
                            .attr("width", canvas_width)
                            .attr("height", canvas_height);

    var tooltip = d3.select(DOMElement).append("div")
                                    .classed("tooltip", true);


    // interaction settings
    var tooltipText = function(d, i){return "tooltip over element "+i;}
    var mouseoverCallback = function(d, i){ };
    var mouseoutCallback = function(d, i){ };
    var mouseclickCallback = function(d, i){ console.log(d,i)};
    var keySelected = null;

    // ---- PRIVATE FUNCTIONS

    function render(){
        GUP_scat();
    }

    function GUP_scat(){

        // GUP
        // Create Circles
        svg.selectAll("circle")
                .data(dataset)
                .enter()
                .append("circle")  // Add circle svg
                .attr("cx", function(d) {
                        return xScale(d[0]);  // Circle's X
                })
                .attr("cy", function(d) {  // Circle's Y
                        return yScale(d[1]);
                })
                .attr("r", 2);  // radius

        // Add to X axis
        svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (canvas_height - padding) +")")
                .call(xAxis);

        // Add to Y axis
        svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding +",0)")
                .call(yAxis);

        // On click, update with new data
        d3.select(DOMElement)
                .on("click", function() {
                    keySelected = (keySelected == d.key) ? null : d.key;

                    var numValues = dataset.length;  // Get original dataset's length
                                     dataset = [];  // Initialize empty array
                                     for(var i=0; i<numValues; i++) {
                                             var newNumber1 = d.value.x;  // Random int for x
                                             var newNumber2 = d.value.y;  // Random int for y
                                             dataset.push([newNumber1, newNumber2]);  // Add new numbers to array
                                     }

                        // Update scale domains
                        xScale.domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
                                return d[0]; })]);
                        yScale.domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
                                return d[1]; })]);

                        // Update circles
                        svg.selectAll("circle")
                                .data(dataset)  // Update with new data
                                .transition()  // Transition from old to new
                                .duration(1000)  // Length of animation
                                .each("start", function() {  // Start animation
                                        d3.select(this)  // 'this' means the current element
                                                .attr("fill", "red")  // Change color
                                                .attr("r", 5);  // Change size
                                })
                                .delay(function(d, i) {
                                        return i / dataset.length * 500;  // Dynamic delay (i.e. each item delays a little longer)
                                })
                                //.ease("linear")  // Transition easing - default 'variable' (i.e. has acceleration), also: 'circle', 'elastic', 'bounce', 'linear'
                                .attr("cx", function(d) {
                                        return xScale(d[0]);  // Circle's X
                                })
                                .attr("cy", function(d) {
                                        return yScale(d[1]);  // Circle's Y
                                })
                                .each("end", function() {  // End animation
                                        d3.select(this)  // 'this' means the current element
                                                .transition()
                                                .duration(500)
                                                .attr("fill", "black")  // Change color
                                                .attr("r", 2);  // Change radius
                                });

                                // Update X Axis
                                svg.select(".x.axis")
                                        .transition()
                                        .duration(1000)
                                        .call(xAxis);

                                // Update Y Axis
                                svg.select(".y.axis")
                                        .transition()
                                        .duration(100)
                                        .call(yAxis);

                                mouseclickCallback(d, i);
    });}

    return scatObj; // returning the main object
}
```

I am calling it like this in my main.js file :

```
    dash.append('div').attr('id', 'scat1').classed("scatterplot", true)
            .append("h3").text("Per Scateub");

        var scat1 = scatterplot("div#scat1")
            .setTooltipText(function(d, i){
                return "<b>"+d.data.key +" : "+d3.format(",.2f")(d.value)+"</b> /10 ";
        })
            .loadAndRender(dataManager.getFteOverall());

            scat1.setMouseclickCallback(function(d, i){
                dataManager.setNameFilter(d.key);
                redraw();
            })
```

and here is my nest :

```
dmObj.getFteOverall= function(){
    var nestedData = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d){ return d.naAsses;})
        .rollup(function (v) { return {
            x: d3.sum(v,function(d){
                return (d.four*4,d.three*3,d.two*2,d.one)/100 }),
            y: d3.sum(v, function(d){
                return (d.fte)
            }
        )
        };

        })
        .sortKeys(d3.ascending)
        .entries(filteredData());


    return nestedData;
}
```

I know it can seem a bit a stupid question, but I have been struggling with it, and I have already been stuck for a while.
I hope I am clear and you will be able to help me (just in case I am working with d3 V4).
Thanks to advance guys.